# Creating href using Laravel 5 with jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5. I am construction a attachments list using jquery.

my file path is `/files/myfile.jpg`

```
      $('#attachmentList').empty();
            $.each(response, function(key, val) {
                $('<li><a href="{{ asset('+val.filepath+val.filename+') }}">'
                  +val.filename+'</a></li>').appendTo('#attachmentList');
            });
```

this creates `%7B%7B%asset(files/myfile.jpg)%20%7D%7D` url in my address bar.

I need `asset` `url` in the hyperlink. How can I make hyperlink in my view.

Comment: Why will server side templating syntax work from the client side? Create a fully qualified asset URL from the server before sending it to the client side.

Comment: I don't know how to do that? :( Could you explain that?

Comment: Use the `URL::asset` helper in the controller from where you are sending these file paths. It would be best to post the controller code to which you are making your AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the other Blade syntax.

```
  $('#attachmentList').empty();
        $.each(response, function(key, val) {
            $('<li><a href="{!! asset('+val.filepath+val.filename+') !!}">'
              +val.filename+'</a></li>').appendTo('#attachmentList');
        });
```

Comment: Your syntax doesn't look correct. Did you really expect it to work when you use Javascript variable inside a PHP block? I only answered for the *character escaping* problem.